# Create a new unique ID in React JS after users clicks "submit"

Tags: reactjs, state, jsx

Could you please help me to add a final piece of code to my React JS App? So, my program has an initial state of:

```
state = {
    players: [
      {
        name: “Player 1",
        score: 0,
        id: 1,
      }
```

There is also a button in the form with an event listener which allows users to add new players. Function which updates the initial state with provided data looks like this:

```
  handleAddPlayer = (name) => {
    this.setState({
      players: [
        ...this.state.players,
        {
          name: name,
          score: 0,
          id: , // <- Make it unique every time a new player is added
        },
      ],
    });
  };
```

My question is - how can I make it that every time users add a new player, new player receives a unique ID assigned to it? I suppose there is multiple ways to make it work so I would highly appreciate if you show me different options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- Indices `id:this.state.players.length+1` [Not Recommended]
- Current timestamp `+new Date()` unix epoch time \\ e.g. 1593203793398
- A library like [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UUID` in order to achieve that:

```
const genUUID = () => {
  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)
    return v.toString(16)
  })
}
// later in your code
id: genUUID()
```

You can use this function, or install a library that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a use case where I need to generate a new temporary **ID** for a newly created element before it is submitted to the server. But I needed an **INT** ID (not a GUI/UUID) so I could still update the newly created element as if it were part of the original existing data that came from the server.

To solve this issue, I manage a **Global Increment** state that updates a number value starting from **0**. However, this is obviously an issue since it will conflict with the IDs of the existing data that came from the server.

To deal with this problem, I increment these IDs in the **negative**, so the first local ID is **-1**, and then **-2**, and so on. Negative numbers are still **INTs**, and when I submit them, I will treat all negative numbers as NEW and run an **INSERT** into the DB, where as all the others would **UPDATE** the DB.

Since this **Global Increment** state is temporary, every reload resets it to 0 (and obviously anything not saved to the server is wiped too).

So far I have had zero issues with this, and it solved my problems trying to manage NEW data that requires an ID that has yet been assigned from the server.

Hope that helps anyone else looking.